# How to define custom relationships between legacy models in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working with some legacy database models in a Django REST Framework application:

```
class Variable(models.Model):
    var_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    resource_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    resource_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    var_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'variables'

class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'projects'
```

Project and Variable are related models such that when the resource_type of a Variable is 'P', then its resource_id represents the project_id of the Project it belongs to. If the resource_type is something other than 'P, then that Variable belongs to a different type of model. I unfortunately can not make significant changes to the database schema for these models.

Is there a way to define a custom relationship between these two models so that I can treat them as if Variable was defined with a ForeignKey to Project? Or as if Project has a ManyToManyField relationship to Variable? I'd ultimately like to be able to create a nested serializer relationship. Something like:

```
class Variable(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Variable
        fields = ('var_id', 'resource_type', 'resource_id', 'var_name')

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    variables = VariableSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Project
        fields = ('project_id', 'name', 'variables')
```

Thanks!